# Access denied for user 'roop'@'localhost' in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql

```
 satheesh@hadoop:~$  mysql -u roop -p
 Enter password: 
 ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'roop'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This is what I typed in terminal and I am getting error.Help needed!

Comment: your username is 'roop'?

Comment: Use `root` instead of `roop`.

Comment: first try to loin as roop like `su roop` and then try to connect your database.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please dont post error without elaboration! explain what happened and what u want ! Anyways this is just a typo mistake. Please remember these things in future :)